# How can I get Related Keyword in ODATA?

Tags: 2013, odata

I have the following Keyword: 
[image]

The keyword has "Monuments" as a Related Keyword and, "Barcelona" as a Parent Keyword.
I can not see the relation in ODATA

[image]

How Can I get it?

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried publishing the taxonomies?

Comment: Yes, I did. Both taxonomies.

Comment: When you say "don't see the relation in ODATA", what is the url/querytring you're submitting to the web service?